# Can guest user delete custom object records?

Tags: apex, custom-object, delete, dmlexception, guest-user

I have a custom object which is having look up to Account and contact and few other custom objects. Can users with Guest user License delete such records.

I have been trying to delete with an automated process but It hasn't been happening. All the object has been given maximum object level access. Sharing setting of account and contact is Public Read/write.

Comment: How are you deleting? Apex class is with or without sharing?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, It is getting deleted through managed class. So I cannot tell if it is using with or without sharing. But I have given maximum possible object level access to all related objects.

Comment: Object access and record access are different things... can you add a middle class without sharing that calls that manged class methods?

Answer (score 0):

A Guest user is mostly associated with a Force.com Site. **By default, the Site Guest User does not have access to any objects, fields, or VisualForce pages.** You need to enable permissions and page visibility that are applicable to your use case.

Giving full object level permissions might not work in this case as Guest User Profile separately controls the permissions. So, you will need to open the Site --> Navigate to "Public Access Settings". This will open the guest user profile. Here, you need to enable the necessary permissions.

You can only assign the permission to read/create on standard objects, but can assign full create-read-updated-delete (CRUD) on custom objects. Please read https://cloud4good.com/announcements/site-guest-user/. Seems to be helpful.

Comment: As mentioned in my question, all the related objects have been given maximum object level access.